# Show a summary of the reviewed/suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In the page that shows the reviews made by a user, it could be useful to have a summary of the review activity shown at the top of the page; something similar to the following text would suffice:

> Approved suggestions: 39
>   Rejected suggestions: 17
>   Total: 56

Similar text could be shown for the suggestions page, where the text could be something similar to the following one:

> Approved suggestions: 39
>   Rejected suggestions: 17
>   Pending suggestions: 10
>   Total: 66